# Entity Framework Core queries related entries in different ways

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'd like to know why the two EF Core queries below, that return the same thing, actually translate in different SQL statements. And how I could write the first one as a lambda expression? It seems to be more efficient.

**Query 1**

```
var query = from d in _context.Devices
    from e in _context.Events.Where(e => e.DeviceId == d.DeviceId).Take(1)
    select new
    {
      deviceId = d.DeviceId,
      lat = d.Lat,
      lon = d.Lon,
      events = e
    };
```

This one translates in the SQL below (simplified):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Devices] AS [d]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM [Events] AS [e]
    WHERE [e].[DeviceId] = [d].[DeviceId]
) AS [t]
```

**Query 2**

```
var query = _context.Devices.Select(d => new
    {
     deviceId = d.DeviceId,
     lat = d.Lat,
     lon = d.Lon,
     events = d.Events.Take(1)
    });
```

This one instead of using the APPLY, it first SELECTs the Devices and then for each it SELECTs the TOP 1 event:

```
/* run first */
SELECT *
FROM [Devices] AS [d]

/* run for each device */
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM [Events] AS [e]
WHERE @_outer_DeviceId = [e].[DeviceId]
```

Comment: Is this EF Core? Also note that the two queries have different shape - the first returns flat result set with basically (device, event) pairs, while the second returns (device, list of events) pairs. And using query or method syntax has nothing in common with performance (this former is translated to the later by the compiler).

Comment: @IvanStoev yes it's EF Core, and yes, I think you answered my question. I didn't notice that the returns are different!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IvanStoev I noticed that the two queries are basically different:

> the first returns flat result set with basically (device, event)
>   pairs, while the second returns (device, list of events) pairs

This can be seen by changing the number of events with `TOP(2)`:

Query 1:

```
[
{
  "deviceId": 1,
  "lat": 51.44467,
  "lon": -0.21289,
  "events": {
    "min": 1.27,
    "max": 11.1,
    "eventId": 24873
  }
},
{
  "deviceId": 1,
  "lat": 51.44467,
  "lon": -0.21289,
  "events": {
    "min": 1.27,
    "max": 11.1,
    "eventId": 24852
  }
},
{
  "deviceId": 2,
  "lat": 51.48085,
  "lon": -0.16862,
  "events": {
    "min": 32.61,
    "max": 37.24,
    "eventId": 224693
  }
},
{
  "deviceId": 2,
  "lat": 51.48085,
  "lon": -0.16862,
  ...
```

Query 2:

```
[
{
  "deviceId": 1,
  "lat": 51.44467,
  "lon": -0.21289,
  "events": [
    {
      "min": 1.27,
      "max": 11.1,
      "eventId": 24873
    },
    {
      "min": 1.27,
      "max": 11.1,
      "eventId": 24852
    }
  ]
},
{
  "deviceId": 2,
  "lat": 51.48085,
  "lon": -0.16862,
  "events": [
    {
      "min": 32.61,
      "max": 37.24,
      "eventId": 224693
    },
    {
      "min": 32.61,
      "max": 37.24,
      "eventId": 224689
    }
  ]
},
{
  "deviceId": 3,
  "lat": 51.4488,
  "lon": -0.1493,
  "events": [
    {
 ...
```